# What is the error in this string loop?

Tags: java, string

```
for (int i = len-2; index>= 0; index --)
```

Comment: what error gives you? compilation error? runtime exception? be more precise

Comment: You really haven't provided enough information. I assume len refers to str.length()? Why are you ignoring the last character? Why are you using two different indexes? This code makes no sense out of context, and I doubt it makes sense in context.

Comment: The loop body is missing? You should declare `index` as int instead of `i`? You skip the last character?

Answer (score 5):

Without any real context I would venture that `int i` should be replaced with `int index`.

Comment: Also, unless you want to start at the *second to* last character, use (int index = len-1 ...

Answer (score 4):

You are using two variables: `i` and `index`, maybe this is causing trouble to you?

Answer (score 1):

Hard to tell from a single line of code, but why are you initializing i, and the checking and decrementing index? Try:

```
for (int index = len-2; index>= 0; index --)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through the string backwards?  (I suppose that was your intention)

You are also not starting with the very last character in the string, you are starting with the second last (len-2).

Comment: He might be leaving a newline character out of the loop. -1 for 0-based string length, -1 for the newline character (Cr, Lf).

Comment: @Bobby: We don't know that <code>len</code> is <code>str.length()</code>